# Stuck on trig simplification

Tags: trigonometry

Stuck on trig simplification..

How do you reduce  $$\frac{\cos x-1}{x}$$ 
to $$\frac{-\sin x}{1}$$
?

What do I multiply by?

Comment: Derivate both numerator and denominator.

Comment: It is not a **reduction**, it is not a simplification: the two functions are certainly not the same. It is probably part of a L'Hospital's Rule calculation of the limit as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are taking the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x},$$ which is of indeterminate form as $x \to 0$,  then it looks like in the subsequent step, L'Hopital was used to derive the equivalent limit:  $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0} (-\sin x) = 0$$ i.e.  finding the derivative of both the numerator and denominator, and then evaluating the limit of the resultant function as $x\to 0$.

Comment: No, this is circular. To use l'Hopital, you have to use the derivative, but the derivative is exactly this limit. To have a method it is ok, but theoretically it is not sound.

Comment: @LutzL: This may not have been a task of finding the derivative of the given function. It may have been to find the limit as $x\to 0$ of the function, leading up to a soon-to-come lesson in difference quotients. I wrote this thinking perhaps that having evaluated the limit of the function, note that an *indeterminate from* is obtained, which then licenses the use of L'Hopital. We'd need the OP's context in which encountering the problem to know what the task was that  "reduced" the function from the former to the latter.

Comment: @LutzL Please read the original post, and my answer. I clearly specify how I am interpreting the question.

Comment: You are suggesting to use l'Hopitals rule and thus differentiation because differentiation is a yet unknown concept? That seems to hint at a really messed up curriculum.

Comment: Useful and clear answer+1

Comment: Yes, this was is.  It was a limit using L'Hopital's.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @Jack

Answer (score 2):

You use $x=x-0$ and $\cos(0)=1$ to see that your expression is the difference quotient of the cosine function

$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(0)}{x-0}$

and that its limit for $x\to 0$ is the differential quotient or the derivative value at $x=0$.

---

Remark (expanded from comment): To use l'Hopital in this instance (supposing the original task did involve a limit of $x\to 0$) is circular reasoning. One has to determine the derivatives of numerator and denominator, but the derivative of the numerator at $x=0$ is exactly this limit.

To have an easy-to-remember method, application of l'Hopital on limits of the form $\tfrac{f(x)}{x}$ is ok, but theoretically it is not sound.

---

Another interpretation: There is really no limit intended in the question. Then a similar looking result is obtained from an application of the intermediate value theorem. In general

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(\tilde x)$$

for $\tilde x$ in between $a$ and $x$, sometimes formalized as $\tilde x=(1-\theta)a+\theta x$ with $\theta \in (0,1)$.

In this instance, this gives

$$\frac{\cos x-1}{x}=-\sin \tilde x,\quad \tilde x=\theta x,\quad\theta \in(0,1).$$

Exploration of the power series expressions on both sides gives $\tilde x=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^3}{12}+O(x^5)$ for sufficiently small values of $x$.

Comment: You're assuming the task was to find the difference quotient and evaluate at $x \to 0$. It may have simply been to evaluate the *function's limit* as $x\to 0$.

Comment: This explanation doesn't give any reason to write $-\sin x$ as a fraction with denominator $1$, though. L'Hopital seems to be a much better guess at what is going on here.

Comment: This would assume a purely mechanical knowledge of differentiation rules, including advanced topics as l'Hopital. Why the 1 in the denominator is important in the first place is a question for a different place.

Comment: @LutzL: I whole-heartedly agree. Using l'Hopital's in this context is an excessive and unnecessary abuse of a theorem developed ostensibly for problems where other methods were not readily available; however, perhaps it is the most abused (and frequently misabused) method for evaluating limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reduce one to the other by any correct steps. This is because
$$\frac{\cos x -1}{x} \not\equiv -\sin x \, . $$
To see this, let $x=\pi$. We have:
$$\frac{\cos \pi - 1}{\pi} = -\frac{2}{\pi} \ \ \text{and} \ \ -\sin \pi = 0 \, . $$

I suspect that you are interested in the limit of $\frac{\cos x-1}{x}$ as $x$ tends towards zero.

**Notice that a limit is very different to a function**. The two expressions might have the same limit, i.e. they tend towards the same value at the same point, but they need to be the same for all $x$. For example $x^2$ and $x^3$ both go to zero as $x$ goes to zero, but $2^2 \neq 2^3$.

To find the limit, take a look at these two videos on YouTube:

1. [Showing that $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$.](http://youtu.be/o6S6RbfhRTU)
2. [Showing that $\frac{\cos x -1}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=encQhh2JeYc)

Comment: The limit 2., the one of the question, really is only a special case of the limit in 1., since $\cos(x)-1=-2\sin^2(\tfrac{x}{2})$.

Comment: Ok. I didn't watch the videos. Just for the fun of it, another way -- avoiding the one-half factors -- is to expand by $\cos(x)+1$ giving $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x}=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos x+1}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: @LutzL You seem to misunderstand the role of comments. They are to ask for more information or to suggest improvements. If you have another way of answering a post then post/edit your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{\cos x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{-2\sin^2 \frac{x}2}{x}=\lim_{x\to0} \dfrac{-\sin \frac{x}2}{\frac{x}2}\cdot \sin \frac{x}2=-1\cdot\lim_{x\to0} \sin\frac{x}2=0$

where I've used $\cos^2 x=1-2\sin^2 \dfrac{x}2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1.$